# How to host a Laravel website on Netlify?

Tags: laravel, netlify

I'm trying to host my Laravel website on [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/cli/).

I was originally using Laravel Forge to deploy and host my website.
The deploy script that was used on Laravel forge was:

```
cd /home/forge/lucaban.com
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.1-fpm reload

if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan migrate --force
fi
```

Is there any way I can host the website on Netlify and run these composer commands? Because I think I can only insert NodeJS commands into the build command input.

I have not yet succeeded getting my website live...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot host a laravel site on Netlify.  Check out https://jamstack.org for more about the philosophy behind Netlify's hosting service.

While you can use php in the **build** environment (`composer install` should work, though you may want to set `PHP_VERSION` to 7.2 since the default is 5.6), the build process is intended to create static output files - html, css, js, images, etc - which Netlify can then serve from its CDN without running any more code on the server side.  While the comparison is not quite perfect, imagine that the output from your build (limited to 15 minutes and no incoming network connections) is a bunch of files, which are stored on S3 and served as-is.  So if you end up with `file.php` - Netlify would show, not run, the code in the file.

You cannot host a laravel, wordpress, drupal, magento, etc site on Netlify, though it is Netlify and the JAMstack movement's assertion that you don't need a legacy website that runs code at every visit to run much of the web and that there is great value in reducing the dynamic portions of a website to small services, such as [form-handling](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/) or [lambda functions](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/).  Here's a case study on a customer who migrated their site from wordpress to Netlify and includes authentication, comments, and e-commerce:   https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/03/16/smashing-magazine-just-got-10x-faster/

Comment: The JAMStack community backs this answer 100%. Netlify is a continuous deployment platform that will push your static content to new levels! Pick a static site generator from https://www.staticgen.com/ and help save baby seals. Just kidding, but seriously, time to start rethinking stacks that are unnecessary.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go rewrite all those old websites I have in Laravel........ : (

Comment: @mesqueeb Take a look at https://jigsaw.tighten.co/ for something that is PHP/Laravel based but still a static sight generator that will work with Netlify.

I wrote a blog post about a method of *hosting* of a Laravel site with Netlify. https://www.phpjobs.app/blog/hosting-a-laravel-project-with-netlify

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have look at Vapor which is a serverless deployment platform for Laravel:

https://vapor.laravel.com

Comment: This Answer is unrelated to the question

Comment: No, it‘s not: Netlify is a serverless platform which does not support Laravel/PHP. Vapor is – you guessed it – a serverless service which is tailored for Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try these suggestions.

DigitalOcean VMs,
AWS Lambda and Bref,
Laravel Vapor,
Fly.io